# Bonding pincode and connection authentication

Tags: movesense

I tried to configure a bonding pincode on my Movesense 2.0.0 sensor and I was expecting being asked for it when trying to connect to the sensor with MDS or apps like nRF Connect.
But what I got looks identical to Just Works mode, and the bonding PIN is being asked only if I try to pair the device through system's Bluetooth settings. Does it happen because in the first case there's only connection and no pairing? What are the pros/use cases for having the sensor paired at system-level?
I'm looking for a way to prevent unauthorized access (connections, API requests) to sensors from devices not knowing a secret access code (like a PIN). Do BLE/Movesense provide such a mechanism?

Answer (score 1):

Neither Bluetooth nor Movesense offer a way to securely "log in with a secret password". The passkey bonding mechanism that is present in Bluetooth, is only designed with the purpose of avoiding man in the middle attacks, and the passkey must be random everytime since the protocol reveals the key after each attempt. A static passkey which some people use is not allowed per the specification. It might keep away your grandmother from accessing the device, but is not secure at all at a protocol level.

If you bond the device at a system level, the further communication will be secure (encrypted and authenticated) and will for example prevent spoofing attacks. It will also result in quicker device connection setup since GATT caching can be used.

You are not saying what "system" you are using so this is just a general answer.